# Difference between Azure database for MySQL and Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mysql-database

I am learning azure from Microsoft learn using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/azure-database-fundamentals/azure-mysql-database) link. Does anyone know the basic difference between "Azure Database for MySQL" and "Azure SQL Database"? Both seem very similar.

As I am a beginner, can anyone explain the difference in an easy way?

Comment: These are completely different offerings. One is based on [MySql](https://www.mysql.com/), the other one is based on [Microsoft Sql Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2019). Both are RDMS databases. Try googling `mysql vs sql server`

Comment: `Azure Database for MySQL` is paas DB with mysql storage engine and `Azure SQL Database` is paas DB with SQLServer storage engine.

Comment: Thanks, PeterBons and JosephXu. Now these terms make a little more sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok lets start with what is common for both. with Azure prefixed, both are installed in cloud and managed by Microsoft. Meaning Microsoft is responsible for the databases to be installed, up and running with 0 or minimal downtime. I think this is clear.

Now lets start with differences. Please visit the links below and let me know if you have any issues. Thanks!

https://www.guru99.com/sql-vs-mysql.html

https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-vs-sql

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the difference between SQLServer and MySQL. Now it is clear.

Comment: @Murk glad to know that it helped you to understand. Happy learning ahead!

Answer (score 7):

Add to @CoderRambo's answer. The difference between `Azure Database for MySQL` and `Azure SQL Database` is as follows:

1. `Azure Database for MySQL` is powered by the MySQL community edition. We can choose versions 5.6, 5.7, and 8.0.
2. `Azure SQL Database` is SQL Server database engine, based on the latest stable Enterprise Edition of SQL Server.

The only similarity is: they  are all hosted in the Microsoft cloud and fall into the industry category of Platform-as-a-Service (PaaS). So your question is `mysql vs sql server`.

Comment: Yes, I got confused about the two terms, got the difference. Now it is clear. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql is opensource database, where as when you say SQL it refers to Microsoft SQL Server.
In general both are two different types of databases. Microsoft SQL Server is a licensed version.

When you prefix them with Azure, it means they are hosted on cloud , i.e Azure cloud and Microsoft manages them as PAAS(platform as a service).

Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, please, if you could give an example to compare them, it would be easy for me to understand it more.